# Required number of characters in azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I've made an azure search service and it's up and working. I would like for users to be able to search with 3 characters or more.
I have the following texts in different documents:

1. Paracet 200mg
2. Paracet 150mg
3. Kodein/paracetamol SA

When I search for 'par' I get no results. I have to type 5 characters (parac) and I get 1 & 2 as a result. I want this result for 'par' as well. Is this possible? I can't find anything in the documentation on setting the required number of characters for a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best performance, you could enable the "fast" prefix analyzer in your index, which will break down every token into a list of prefixes at indexing time. Here's some additional information on how to do that : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/

This would require you to re-index your data, so if you are creating a brand new index, this is an option.

If re-indexing is not an option, you can instead use the suffix operation '*' in your query.  Here's more information on the suffix operator : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Simple-query-syntax-in-Azure-Search?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I suspect searching using the suffix operator (or re-indexing while using fast prefix analyzer) will also work with the 3rd document you listed (Kodein/paracetamol SA). If it still does not work, it might be due to you using a tokenizer that does not split on the '/' character. The default analyzer should correctly split on '/', but if you are using a custom analyzer it's possible the whole "Kodein/paracetamol" expression get tokenized into a single term, which would explain why a search for parace* does not return the document, since the prefix of the document is "kode…".